# ESP8266 ESP-12F with NodeMCU firmware reboots when using looped GPIO write

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an ESP-12F module that I flashed with the current NodeMCU dev-branch firmware. The module is powered by a >2A power supply. I use 4 GPIO's to control the driver of a little stepper motor ([this is the combo](http://www.dx.com/p/dmdg-uln2003-stepper-motor-driver-module-5v-28byj-48-stepper-motor-for-arduino-349659)).

I wrote a little Lua script ([partially based on the arduino version described here](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Stepper_Motor_5V_4-Phase_5-Wire_%26_ULN2003_Driver_Board_for_Arduino#Example_code)) in ESPlorer to control the motor, and the program does work, the motor turns accordingly, but it reboots the module when I call the function `turn` with too many steps. The limit is at around 180 steps, sometimes a little bit higher, sometimes a little bit below that number.

I'm really new to programming this kind of modules and I'm also just learning Lua, can anybody imagine what happens here and how I can avoid the reboots? BTW: I also tried supplying external 5 Volts to the driver board, but it did not change anything.

This is my script:

```
gpio.mode(5, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(6, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(7, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(0, gpio.OUTPUT)

sg = function (n,v) gpio.write(n, (v == 0 and gpio.LOW or gpio.HIGH)) end

stepRight = function ()
    sg(5,0);sg(6,0);sg(7,0);sg(0,1);
    sg(5,0);sg(6,0);sg(7,1);sg(0,1);
    sg(5,0);sg(6,0);sg(7,1);sg(0,0);
    sg(5,0);sg(6,1);sg(7,1);sg(0,0);
    sg(5,0);sg(6,1);sg(7,0);sg(0,0);
    sg(5,1);sg(6,1);sg(7,0);sg(0,0);
    sg(5,1);sg(6,0);sg(7,0);sg(0,0);
    sg(5,1);sg(6,0);sg(7,0);sg(0,1);
    sg(5,0);sg(6,0);sg(7,0);sg(0,0);
end

turn = function (dir, steps)
  if dir == 'right' then
    for i=0,steps,1 do
      stepRight()
    end
  end
end
```

Here are some details about the module and the firmware:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: dev
    commit: c54bc05ba61fe55f0dccc1a1506791ba41f1d31b
    SSL: true
    modules: adc,cjson,crypto,dht,file,gpio,hmc5883l,http,i2c,l3g4200d,mqtt,net,node,ow,pwm,spi,tmr,tsl2561,uart,wifi
 build  built on: 2016-11-21 19:02
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4.1(39cb9a32)
```

This is what it looks like when I call the `turn` function with a too high value:

```
turn('right',200)

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x40100000, len 26144, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0x95
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2288, room 8 
tail 8
chksum 0xa8
load 0x3ffe88f0, len 8, room 0 
tail 8
chksum 0x66
csum 0x66
����o�r��n|�llll`��r�l�l��

NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: dev
    commit: c54bc05ba61fe55f0dccc1a1506791ba41f1d31b
    SSL: true
    modules: adc,cjson,crypto,dht,file,gpio,hmc5883l,http,i2c,l3g4200d,mqtt,net,node,ow,pwm,spi,tmr,tsl2561,uart,wifi
 build  built on: 2016-11-21 19:02
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4.1(39cb9a32)
lua: cannot open init.lua
>
```

***Update: I found a solution that works, but I can't explain why. Maybe someone can shed some light on this?***

I thought that I had to approach the problem by finding out when and how the reboot occurs, so I added a little timer delay to the for loop:

```
for i=0,steps,1 do
  stepRight()
  tmr.delay(10)
end
```

This does not affect the speed of the motor in any noticable way, but now I can easily crank up the numbers as high as I want ;) I can use `turn('right',200000)` and the reboot is completely gone, it did not reoccur even once, even if I set the delay to only 1 µs. That's great - but I'd love to know why that helps?

Comment: This happens also in dry-mode, right (driver board disconnected)? Looking at the number of modules compiled into your firmware I'm actually surprised you even got this far. Try reducing to what you really need. It'll free some memory.

Comment: You're right, I disconnected the driver and it's the same behaviour. After reading your comment I know what do do next - I had no idea how much I can savely put into my firmware (as there obviously are no precompiled binaries available anymore). I'm just starting to get a feeling for how to work with these tiny machines. Thank you!

Comment: You may also want to keep an eye on `node.heap()`. And of course the [NodeMCU Lua developer FAQ](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/lua-developer-faq/) for hints how to reduce the footprint :)

Comment: I think there must be something else going on: I just built a minimal firmware, flashed it to the module and added *print(node.heap())* to the end of the *stepRight*-function, the last logged heap output value before the reboot is 41184. I'm not sure if that is ok, but it does not seem to be too low, or is it?

Comment: The number of modules shouldn't affect the _heap_ unless they're put to use. 40k is perfectly fine. I don't understand enough of the inner workings of hardware/SDK/firmware but seeing that `tmr.delay()` helps I suspect that the watchdog reset the device. You may want to check with [`node.bootreason()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/node/#nodebootreason). Also, is your stepper motor a Switec X.27 or compatible? There's a dedicated module for those.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `sg()`7,200 times in a single turn function.  You have to break your processing up to avoid time-outs.  This is just the way that the ESP8266 SDK requires.

Read [my FAQ](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/lua-developer-faq/) in the documentation for a more detailed discussion.